# How to fix org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations

I have a Java Spring MVC web application. Now I have the following controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("module/car")
public class CrentalCarController 
{
@Autowired
@Qualifier("restClientService")
private RESTClientService  restClientService;

//the remaining codes
}
```

I have another interface as follows:

```
public interface RESTClientService
{
}
```

and also a class implementing the above interface. This interface is in a different project that is added as a dependency to the project containing the controller I mentioned in the beginning.  Once I add the

```
@Autowired
    @Qualifier("restClientService")
    private RESTClientService  restClientService;
```

to my controller, I get the following error in console:

```
 ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'crentalCarController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.smartwcm.commons.rest.RESTClientService com.smartwcm.admin.crental.CrentalCarController.restClientService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.smartwcm.commons.rest.RESTClientService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=restClientService)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) ~[spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) ~[spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4720) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
```

I am unable to figure out the exact issue, I am not sure if I am doing anything wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

com.smartwcm.commons.rest.RESTClientService

this bean is not mapped anywhere..
either add it to your configurations xml or maybe try :

```
@Component
public interface RESTClientService
    {
    }
```

also..if you don't have more than one declaration of the same bean then you wouldn't need the Qualifier annotation..for more refer: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_qualifier_annotation.htm